# PHP: Fastest way to copy data from two-dimensional array to one-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a huge two-dimensional PHP array with 5M rows.

```
$t = [
  [ "id" => 1, "name" => "foo" ], [ "id" => 2, "name" => "bar" ]
];
```

Now, I have to reduce the ids of this array into one dimension:

```
$o = [ 1, 2 ];
```

Right now, I am using a `foreach` loop that is extremely slow (taking over 100s for the 5M entries:

```
foreach ($t as $v){
  array_push($o, $v['id']);
};
```

I have tried using `for` instead. That gave me a little time advantage but still is taking a long time.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: whats the source of the first array?

Comment: you should be able to return the data in a way so that you dont have to do this

Comment: @Dagon I could adjust the query but I need other data as well that is returned. Dissecting the array in PHP is faster than repeating the (pretty expensive) query.

Comment: i would bet there are better ways to approach this, but you don't want to do that, your call.

Comment: @horen: why not build the two arrays while fetching the db data? easy enough to do `while($row = ...)  { $o[] = $row['id']; $everything[] = $row; }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
$o = array_column($t, 'id');
```

instead? Relevant docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

Comment: `array_column()` with 1K elements 0.09000205993652343750 seconds
`foreach()` 0.23000478744506835938 seconds